# How to disallow users from sharing a certain URL in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, url, sharing

I am looking for something analogous to (robots.txt to search engines). Something to deny sharing a certain URL in Facebook.
In other words, can I tell Facebook that a certain URL should not be shared?
i.e. having a public page protected from sharing, for any reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If people just share the link, I don't think you have any chances to restrict that if the link's URL is public.

Concerning the crawling of the URL, you could disallow the Facebook crawler to index the URL. But I guess that's not exactly what you want.

See

- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47896/how-can-an-exception-be-created-for-facebook-on-robots-txt
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler

Comment: I am not talking about crawling, I am talking about my right to deny facebook from sharing a certain URL of mine.

Comment: Well, if your URL is public, how should this work then? There is no API etc. for that.